# Bash Script - If statement within quoted command

Tags: sql, linux, bash, select

Within a bash script I am running a sql query via 'psql -c '. Based off of the arguements given to the bash script, the where claus of the select command will be different. So basically I need to know if its possible to do something like this:

```
psql -c "select statement here until we get to the where clause at which point we break out of statement and do"
if (arg1 was given)
    concatenate "where arg1" to the end of the above select statement
if (arg2 was given)
    concatenate "where arg2" to the end of the above select statement
```

and so on for as many arguments. I know I could do this much easier in a sql function if I just passed the arguments but that really isnt an option. Thanks!

Edit: 5 seconds after posting this I realize I could just create a string before calling the psql command and then call the psql command on that. Doh!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
psql -c "SELECT columns FROM table ${1:+WHERE $1} ${2:+WHERE $2}"
```

This uses the "use alternate value" substitution - `${VAR:+alternate}` - where `alternate` is substituted if `$VAR` is set and not empty. If `$VAR` is empty, nothing will be substituted.

Comment: Woah - very nice. That saves me a lot of unnecessary stuff. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Save ascript, e.g. query.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

query="select statement here until we get to the where clause at which point we break out of statement and do"

if [ $# -gt 0 ]
then
    query+=" where $1"
    shift
fi

while [ $# -gt 0 ]
then
    query+=" and $1"
    shift
fi

psql -c "$query"
```

Call it like

```
chmod +x ./query.sh
./query.sh "id in (1,2,3)" "modified_by='myname'"
```

Comment: There should be a space after each [ and before each ]

Answer (score 1):

```
SQL="select x,y,z FROM foobar"
if [ "$1" != "" ]
then
   SQL="$SQL where $1"
fi
psql "$SQL"
```

Comment: Yeah, shame that it doesn't do what the OP asked. What happens to arg2? Also psql lacks the -c flag at the moment

Answer (score 0):

```
stmt="select statement here until we get to the where clause at which point we break out of statement and do"

if (( $# > 0 ))
then
    stmt="$stmt where $1"
fi
if (( $# > 1 ))
then
    stmt="$stmt where $2"
fi

psql -c "$stmt"
```